# Always use \NewDocumentCommand instead of \newcommand?

Tags: macros, latex3

Are there compelling reasons to stick with `\newcommand` or should one always use `\NewDocumentCommand` instead, even when not using any of the additional features offered by `xparse`?

In addition and more specifically,

- If I already require `xparse` to define one of the macros of my document/package/class, is it a good idea to use `\NewDocumentCommand` for all my other macro definitions?
- Will `\newcommand` eventually get deprecated/discouraged in favor of `\NewDocumentCommand` with LaTeX3?

Comment: You should use `\newcommand` which will never be deprecated. `\NewDocumentCommand` is from the experimental LaTeX3 and more a command for package writers.

Comment: @Herbert I have to disagree here. yes \DeclareNewCommand is from the latex3 code in the version that runs on top of current LaTeX but the days that we classified all of that as experimental is long gone. These days there is a large stable part (kernel code of expl3 and some packages of which xparse is one). Also xparse is "user interface" for LaTeX2e-like syntax.

Comment: @Frank: then you should change the description of what LaTeX3 will be ;-)

Comment: `NewDocumentCommand` is integrated into all new latex kernels for years as of 2022.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`\NewDocumentCommand` is part of `xparse`, which is 'LaTeX3-in-2e' code. The team have marked this part as 'stable', meaning that we will maintain this code for use with LaTeX2e in an ongoing sense. As such, there is no danger of `\NewDocumentCommand` vanishing.

Conceptually, `\NewDocumentCommand` is intended for 'package authors' to define *commands*, while `\newcommand` is rather more fluid as it is also used to create variables (macros used as storage). This makes `\newcommand` a better choice if what you are defining is a variable: we do not have a 'document level' LaTeX3 command for this concept at present. So the decision will depend to some extent on how you see the macros you are defining (commands with no arguments and variables are pretty hard to distinguish!).

Predicting the future is risky, but I think it's extremely unlikely that any stand-alone LaTeX3 format would not define `\newcommand`, even if the recommendation might be to use other methods. In any case, there  are lots of other concepts that I suspect mean that for some arbitrary LaTeX2e document, you won't just be able to process with a stand-alone LaTeX3 format without adjustment.

Comment: Sorry to dredge up an old thread, but `\NewDocumentCommand` *can* create a command that takes no arguments, so this way would (presumeably) be preferred for things like `\maketitle` (not variables). Has there been any further discussion on this since February that can be referenced?

Comment: @SeanAllred I know it can, but what I mean is that 'insert a token list' can be viewed as a command with no arguments or the use of a token list variable.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I.e. what is actually *stopping* something like make title from being used as, say, a stack. Gotcha.

Comment: @JosephWright is this answer still valid? The `xparse` package documentation dated 23rd of August, 2018 states: “The `xparse` package provides a high-level interface for producing document-level commands. In that way, it is intended as a replacement for the LATEX 2 ε `\newcommand` macro.”

Answer (score 33):

To expand Joseph's answer about commands and values: Macros defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` are robust, they don't get expanded when e.g. moved to the `.toc`. This is a good thing for commands like `\cite` which should *do* something in the `.toc` but in general is not wanted for values which can change in a document and where you want to transport the current *content* to the `.toc` and not only the name of the command. As an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand\testA{}{ABC}
\newcommand\testB{ABC}

\tableofcontents

\RenewDocumentCommand\testA{}{CDE}
\renewcommand\testB{CDE}

\section{\testA, \testB}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Has something changed since this answer was written? Running on a recent TeXLive installation this produces a table of contents that reads "1 CDE, CDE".

Comment: @N.Virgo you no longer need to load xparse, but apart from this it still works as described in the answer. On a current texlive I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8X4W.png. You can also try on https://texlive.net/run