# Passing arguments from a parent function to an auxiliary/child function in xparse

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

**Motivation**

I'm working on a custom `\Colour` command/environment. I'd like to have two mandatory arguments, one taking comma-separated parameters and the second taking the body. My approach for the comma-separated part uses `xparse`'s `\SplitArgument`. Is it possible to get the parent function to pass an argument to its auxiliary/child function?

**Current version**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{
    xparse,
    amsmath,
    xcolor
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ColourAux}{m m m m}{
    \newcommand{\Coloured}{\color{#1}#4}
    \tl_if_empty:nTF { #2 } { \newcommand{\Body}{\begin{aligned}\Coloured\end{aligned}} }{
        \str_case:nnF { #2 } {
            { t }{ \newcommand{\Body}{\text{\Coloured}} }
            { i }{ \newcommand{\Body}{\textit{\Coloured}} }
            { b }{ \newcommand{\Body}{\textbf{\Coloured}} }
            { ib }{ \newcommand{\Body}{\textit{\textbf{\Coloured}}} }
            { bi }{ \newcommand{\Body}{\textit{\textbf{\Coloured}}} }
        } {  }
    }
    \tl_if_empty:nTF { #3 } { \Body } { \parbox{#3}{\Body} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand{\Colour}{>{\SplitArgument{3}{,}}m}{\ColourAux#1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        & \Colour{red,ib,4cm,the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog} \\ % works as desired
        % & \Colour{red,ib,4cm}{the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog} \\ % desired syntax
        & \Colour{red,,,\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}} \\ % works as desired
        % & \Colour{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}} % desired syntax
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 1:** with thanks to Steven B. Segletes, is it possible to do this with `expl3`/`xparse`?

**Edit 2:** in response to egreg's comment, I've found and implemented a suggestion from an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98157/235895) by Joseph Wright to use `\newcommand` to store variables.

Comment: Start with avoiding `\def` at ***all*** costs.

Comment: @egreg I had no idea. Why, and what should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't speak Expl3, I will leave the revision of `\ColourAux` to others.  But here, I show how `\Colour` can be revised to achieve the desired syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{
    amsmath,
    xcolor
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ColourAux}{m m m m}{
    \def\Coloured{\color{#1}#4}
    \tl_if_empty:nTF { #2 } { \def\Body{\begin{aligned}\Coloured\end{aligned}} }{
        \str_case:nnF{#2}{
            { t }{ \def\Body{\text{\Coloured}} }
            { i }{ \def\Body{\textit{\Coloured}} }
            { b }{ \def\Body{\textbf{\Coloured}} }
            { ib }{ \def\Body{\textit{\textbf{\Coloured}}} }
            { bi }{ \def\Body{\textit{\textbf{\Coloured}}} }
        }{}
    }
    \tl_if_empty:nTF { #3 } { \Body } { \parbox{#3}{\Body} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\Colour[2]{%
  \readlist*\z{#1,,}%
  \edef\zz{{\z[1]}{\z[2]}{\z[3]}}%
  \expandafter\ColourAux\zz{#2}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
         & \Colour{red,ib,4cm}{the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog} \\ % desired syntax
         & \Colour{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}} % desired syntax
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]