# Should users use \NewDocumentCommand in place of \newcommand in 2021?

Tags: xparse, renewcommand

It's eight years since someone asked [Always use \NewDocumentCommand instead of \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98152/always-use-newdocumentcommand-instead-of-newcommand) and as I approach the chapter on defining new commands in my LaTeX book, I'm wondering if it makes sense for the default command that users should use for creating their own commands and shortcuts should be `\NewDocumentCommand` et al. The edge case appears to be where you might want to have the contents of the command expand at write to aux time, e.g., `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{...}` instead of `\RenewDocumentCommand{\thechapter}{...}` but it seems to me that the vast majority of cases that a document writer is defining new commands, she would be better served with the `xparse` commands rather than the older LaTeX2.09-style commands.

Comment: You know that any new idea, no matter how great it is (especially if it's great) will take a generation to be accepted.  That is, until the practitioners, protectors, and defenders literally die off, it won't happen.  That said, you leave my `\newcommand` alone!!  (Either that, or `\let\oldcommand\newcommand \let\newcommand\NewDocumentCommand`)

Comment: Joseph had just an article in tugboat about it, and there is his blog https://www.texdev.net/2020/08/20/newdocumentcommand-versus-newcommand-versus

Comment: probably yes, especially as you don't need to mention xparse any more: \NewDocumentCommand is in the format just as \newcommand is.

Comment: What others said plus `\RenewDocumentCommand{\thechapter}{...}` is wrong because `\thechapter` will be `\protected` and often you don't want `\the<counter>` to be `\protected`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik You mean where, in the question, I raised the edge case 

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Grr to xparse issuing a `LaTeX3 error` rather than `LaTeX error`. The appendix about dealing with errors gets a little organizationally weird thanks to that.

Comment: @DonHosek Right, I misread. Sorry :)

Comment: You can use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` though instead of \newcommand to get the non protected, expandable version

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So the plan is that it will be `LaTeX error` in a future release?

Comment: There was some rationalization of the messages but I may have mis-remembered the details (it's still latex3 in latex-dev) I'll delete that comment now and check