# When to use \NewDocumentCommand vs. \newcommand

Tags: macros, texstudio, vscode

I'm a layperson who is wondering about the difference between `\NewDocumentCommand` and `\newcommand`. I don't know when to choose one or the other.

I'm asking because *The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX* recommends that we should move to `\NewDocumentCommand`, but my `LaTeX` editor, `VSCode`, does not automatically add my macros to the suggested list when I'm using `\NewDocumentCommand`, but `TeXstudio` does.

Comment: Related: [Always use \NewDocumentCommand instead of \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98152/2693)

Comment: I *think* `\newcommand*\command{}` is more efficient when  no arguments are involved, but I might be misremembering.

Comment: @cfr it is (but you won't tell unless you call it millions of times, and the result is different, one is `\protected\def`, the othe `\def`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not worth remembering, then?